# How to Create Two Columns from One Column in SQL Based on a IF argument in Another Column

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, select

I have a table that has 3 columns. Value, condition and day. I would like to SELECT two columns from column Value. One which is average value of t.value grouped by t.condition 1 and another one which is an average value of t.value grouped by t.condition 2. I would then like to group them all by day and condition.

[image: Table]

Result should look like this table.

[image: expected result]

I have tried case when, if and CTEs. However, they all failed. The if statement work for fulfilling one condition but seeing that condition is binary, the if function i tried did not work. I have considered creating two tables and then joining on day. That would work I would assume. Would there be an easier way of doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select day,
       max(case when condition = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when condition = 2 then value end) as value_2
from t
group by day;
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! I tried case when but I kept doing it wrong obviously! Thank you so much! :))